# How can I fix this error? "The name 'TextBox1' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Add_drugs2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\R.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     }

     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          cmd.CommandText = "insert into drugs2 (Science_name) values('" + TextBox1.Text + "');

          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

This is my markup file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="152px"></asp:TextBox>
```

I get this error

> The name 'TextBox1' does not exist in the current context

How can I fix this error? I try to add the data to my database

Comment: Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough! – Check this site: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You need to create a [mcve]. Narrow down enough code that still reproduces your problem. Show nothing more or less than exactly what is needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you write the correct code because i am beginner in webforms?

Comment: No, we can't. There's several reasons you can get this error, and you haven't provided sufficient code to demonstrate which one it is. We aren't here to just write your code for you. We are here to fix problems, but you have to give sufficient info so we can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are several possible issues here.

First up, you don't show any more markup then JUST your text box.

In most cases, just dropping a text box into the markup will work, and should work.

However, there are quite a few exceptions, such as placing the text box inside of a repeater, or even a listview, or gridview.

So, I would for starters create a blank new web page.

Then, from the tool box drag + drop in the text box.

So, we have this:

[image]

So you probably have messed up the markup on your page. It should look similar to above.

And now our code, say like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sCon =
        @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\R.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sCon))
    {
        string strSQL =
            "insert into drugs2 (Science_name) values(@sname)";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

So, keep in mind that if your text box is "nested" inside of many of the so called data bound controls (listview, gridview, repeater etc.), then you can't use the control name directly (you need to share more of your markup, and then we can help figure out your issue better).